# Задача о ханойских башнях

Tags: perl

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, что не так в коде, я его запускаю - компьютер зависает..Исправила кое-что, но повторно запускать что-то боюсь..
Это задача о ханойских башнях.

```
use encoding 'cp1251', STDOUT => 'cp866', STDIN => 'cp866';
#! /bin/usr/perl
print "Задача о ханойских башнях\n";
print "Задайте число дисков на стержне А (не более 8)\n";

sub Hanoi{
my (@A,@B,@C,$n) = @_;
#print @A;
if ($n == 1){
my ($k) = pop(@A);
 push (@C,$k);
 #print "Стержень \@A: \n";
 #print @A;
 #print "Стержень \@B: \n";
# print @B;
 #print "Стержень \@C: \n";
 #print @C;
 return (print "Снять диск со стержня \@A и положить на стержень \@C ;\n"); 
 }
  else{
  Hanoi(@A,@C,@B,$n-1); 
  print "Cнять диск со стержня \@A и положить на стержень \@C\n";
  Hanoi(@B,@A,@C,$n-1);
  }

  }

$num = <STDIN>;
for ($num) {
s/^\s+//;
s/\s+$//;
}
$num + 0;
@A = ();
@B = ();
@C = ();
for ($i = $num; $i>0;$i--){
push(@A,$i);
print "A[\$i] = $i\n";
}

Hanoi(@A,@B,@C,$num);
```

Может кто из вас осмелится запустить - проверить, работает это или нет..

Comment: my (@A,@B,@C,$n) = @_; 
Всё, что есть в @_ скопируется в @A

Comment: а не надо все в @A, надо как в вызове 


     Hanoi(@A,@B,@C,$num);

Comment: Тогда передавайте ссылки на массив, и работайте с ссылками на массив

Comment: не работает ни со ссылками, ни без них((( что же здесь не так...

Comment: Покажите как вы делаете ссылками

Comment: Hanoi(\@A,\@B,\@C,$num);

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.14;
use utf8;
sub hanoi {
    my ($a, $b, $c, $n) = @_;
    if($n == 1) {
        push($c, pop($a));
        return print "\@A -> \@C\n";
    }
    else {
        hanoi($a, $c, $b, $n - 1);
        print "\@A -> \@B\n";
        hanoi($b, $a, $c, $n - 1);
    }
}

my $a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
my $b = [];
my $c = [];
hanoi($a, $b, $c, 4);
```

P.S Я не исправлял ваш алгоритм